# How to create custom volume for my application

Tags: java, android, android-widget

I'm trying to create a custom volume button, but I have not stopped with any Statute or any ideas to help me develop it.
I go to publish my question after having searched a lot on the net and have not found anything.

What I do is something like this:

[image: Volume]

or like this:

[image]

I just need an idea, or a tutorial that any of you know ...

thank you very much for reading

Answer (score 1):

To control the volume on the phone, you will need to use the [AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) class.  This gives you all the necessary methods for modifying the volume from various audio streams on the device.  For example, this will change the media volume:

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager) Context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, [int direction], [int flags]);
```

As for the UI of the volume control, you can use most and UI widget you want, like a [SeekBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html), or even a custom component.  There are multiple tutorials online for various types of widgets you can use for the UI.